# iOS Keyboard Rotating on a Fixed Landscape Orientation

Tags: ios, orientation

I'm working on a iOS 6 iPad app. In the Target Summary page I've set the orientation to landscape.

From one screen I have a modal view appearing and when it does the keyboard automaically appears i.e. using `becomeFirstResponder` in the `ViewDidLoad` method

However when it appears it animates/rotates from the 'portrait' postion rather than simply appearing from the bottom.

Any ideas on this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

try moving the `becomeFirstResponder` call out of `viewDidLoad` and into `viewDidAppear`